# Array List Search

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing some past exam papers in preparation for a forthcoming exam, and have come across this question, and I'm not sure how to solve it, I've written a for-each loop with an if statement but I'm not sure what the header would be and what to return. Any help would be great. Thanks.

The question:

> An ArrayList named classList is used
>   to store Student objects.
>
> Write code for a method that
>   determines whether or not data for a
>   student with given forename and
>   surname is present in classList.

Comment: The question states what you need to provide as input and what the output would be.  I don't see what your doubt is.

Comment: If you try showing the for-loop you've done so far, and what the Student class looks like, then you'll have more luck in getting an answer that helps you.

Comment: What do you mean by "header"? As for return type: what kind of answer is your function supposed to give to the question "is the student [first name] [last name] in the list?" -- "yes" or "no" right? `boolean`s are great for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
boolean lala( Student given ) {
  for( Student s : classList ) {
    if( s.getForename().equals( given.getForename() ) &&
        s.getSurname().equals( given.getSurname() ) ) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok I had something like that.. just wasn't sure on the header/return. Thanks very much Mike!

Answer (score 2):

```
static boolean isPresentInList(List<Student> students, String forename, String surname)
{
     // loop thru students and check forename and surname and if there is a match, 
     // return true
     // outside of loop return false (no match).

     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
private static ArrayList<Student> findStudents(ArrayList<Student> students, Student student) {
    ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<Student>();
    for (Student obj: students) {
        if (obj.getFirstname().equals(student.getFirstname()) &&
            obj.getLastname().equals(student.getLastname())) {
            result.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

class Student {
    private String mFirstname;
    private String mLastname;

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String fistName, String lastName) {
        mFirstname = fistName;
        mLastname = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return mFirstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String mFirstname) {
        this.mFirstname = mFirstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return mLastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String mLastName) {
        this.mLastname = mLastName;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentList.add(new Student("eder", "quiñones"));
        studentList.add(new Student("eder", "orteag"));
        studentList.add(new Student("lucia", "germes"));
        studentList.add(new Student("chespirito", "gomez"));

        System.out.println(findAllStudentsByName(studentList, "eder"));
        System.out.println(findAllStudentsByName(studentList, "lucia"));
        System.out.println(findAllStudentsByLastName(studentList, "germes"));
        System.out.println(findStudents(studentList, new Student("eder", "quiñones")));
    }

    private static ArrayList<Student> findAllStudentsByName(ArrayList<Student> students, String firstName) {
        ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for (Student obj: students) {
            if (obj.getFirstname().equals(firstName)) {
                result.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Student> findAllStudentsByLastName(ArrayList<Student> students, String lastName) {
        ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for (Student obj: students) {
            if (obj.getLastname().equals(lastName)) {
                result.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return result;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Returning an Array of objects just in case that we have more than one student with the 
same firstname or lastname.

Comment: Your findAllStudentsByLastName() is never called. Also you probably want to do it all in one function otherwise you have to go over the whole array twice.

Comment: @Mike you're right the function is never called!, but it works!

Comment: If it's never called, it shouldn't be written.

Comment: @dantuch, it's just an example. I just paste it, just in case that he wanted to use it or not, but it's 100% compilable and I believe that's what matters!